# set texts from database into textviews

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-sqlite, onitemclicklistener

i have a problem which is i have a list of datat from my database .. i want when i click on an item it starts new activity and display the rest of selected item datas into textviews ..
this is my code :

```
userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT FROM"
                +DbHelper.TABLE_NAME+"WHERE"+DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+arg3, null);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BookDetails.class);
            startActivity(i);
            t1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_NAME)));
            t2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_AUTHOR)));
            t3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ISBN)));
            t1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_COPIES)));
            t1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_INFO)));
        }
    });}
```

but it didn't work .. when i click on item the application will stop and exit !
can someone help me please ????
is there better way than this to do it ??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

t1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_NAME))+""); or 
t1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_NAME)).toString());

Answer (score 0):

When asking about a "force close" problem, please include the exception stacktrace from logcat.

There are SQL syntax problems here that will cause an exception:

```
Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT FROM"
+DbHelper.TABLE_NAME+"WHERE"+DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+arg3, null);
```

- You need to specify columns you're selecting. `SELECT *` to select all columns
- You need to have whitespace between keywords like `FROM` and `WHERE` and identifiers like table or column name.
- It's better to use `?` variable binding instead of hardcoding variable values in query.

So, something like this:

```
Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
+DbHelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+DbHelper.KEY_ID+"=?", new String[] { arg3 });
```

Also note that you're overwriting the text in `t1` twice. But that won't cause an exception.